# Plotly heatmap order of columns

Tags: r, heatmap, plotly

Probably an easy one:

I have a numeric matrix with NA's:

```
mat <- matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,19.24,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,17.67,17.67,17.67,17.67,17.67,17.67,19.24,13.48,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,17.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,13.48),
                     nrow=9,ncol=10)
colnames(mat) <- c("11","5","6","2","10","7","4","3","9","8")
rownames(mat) <- c("biological adhesion","cell adhesion","cell communication",
                   "cell surface receptor signaling pathway","cellular response to stimulus",
                   "signal transduction","signaling","single organism signaling",
                   "single organismal cell-cell adhesion")
```

I want to plot it as a heatmap using `plotly`:

```
require(plotly)
plot_ly(x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),z=mat,type="heatmap")
```

[image]

But the column labels don't seem to follow the one I specify:

```
> colnames(mat)
 [1] "11" "5"  "6"  "2"  "10" "7"  "4"  "3"  "9"  "8"
```

Any idea?

In addition, any way to make the y-axis labels entirely visible?

Comment: Looks like `plot_ly` is sorting the axis labels - maybe a bug? For the margin part: you could try adding `%>% plotly::layout(margin=list(l=300))` to give the labels more space.

Comment: Yeah. My problem with setting margins is that it needs tending every time this code needs to be run on a different data set wth different row labels. For x-axis labels plotly does manage to figure out the tick angle and margins, so I'm surprised that for the y-axis one needs to play around with margins

Comment: Maybe the maximum number of chars gives you a multiplier for the margin. Considering the sorting "bug": `plot_ly() %>% add_heatmap(z = ~mat, x = factor(colnames(mat), lev = colnames(mat)), y =  factor(rownames(mat), lev = rownames(mat))) %>% layout(margin = list(l=250))` does the trick, it's documented here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/863 . I think the latest development version (8 days ago) has a fix: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/29238e5e681d8446db7909b0f758648c2ef1772c

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify that plotly should not change the category order by changing the following layout option:

```
p <- plot_ly(z = mat, x = colnames(mat), y=rownames(mat),type="heatmap") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(categoryorder = "trace"))
p
```